# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from `categories` where `id` in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Guys I need help for this issue .
it was working normaly today i got this issue
how i can fix this please ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw0Rt.png)

Comment: Add code and error messages as text not as image

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using the `whereIn` function by the query. So the 1st parameter is the `string` of the key you want to search and the 2nd parameter is the `array` values.

I saw by the image that you are passing extra keys (`position`), so do `->pluck('id')` to get just an array of ids without the other key.

Your code should have something like this:

```
Categories::whereIn('id', [260, 603]);
```

You can see more of the function [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-wherein) and [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-pluck) on the Laravel Collections.